# Need some Graph Invariant Computations

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have found a list of graph invariants at the house of graphs (HOG) [here](https://hog.grinvin.org/). I am able to compute almost all of them with Mathematica and [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).  I am missing computations for the following:

Genus,  Longest Induced Cycle, Longest Induced Path, Minimum Dominating Set

I realize these are probably all NP hard computations. But a brute force algorithm is OK if you can provide one.  My code that computes these variants is at the bottom of this post.  If you see other variants that should be added to a more or less "comprehensive" invariants set please suggest those.  Also, if you see any errors in my computations of these invariants let me know.
Thanks!

```
(* Start with a clean slate and import IGraph*)
ClearAll["Global`*"]
clawGraph = 
  Graph3D[GraphData[{"CompleteBipartite", {1, 3}}], 
   PlotLabel -> "Claw Graph"];
splash[] := (
  Print[Framed[<< "IGraphM`", Background -> Yellow]];
  Print[Framed[
    Style["Computing Graph Invariants 0.1 6/4/22 by Phillip D. \
Neumiller", Bold, FontFamily -> "Bradley Hand ITC", Blue], 
    Background -> LightBlue]];
  
  )
(* Determine Algebraic Connectivity of graph G.  Approximate \
algorithm is find Laplacian (aka Kirchoff Matrix), and find the \
second smallest eigen value. *)
algebraicConnectivity[g_] := (
  \[ScriptCapitalL] = KirchhoffMatrix[g];
  \[ScriptCapitalE] = Eigenvalues[\[ScriptCapitalL]];
  \[ScriptCapitalO] = Sort[Abs[\[ScriptCapitalE] ], GreaterEqual];
  \[ScriptCapitalO][[-2]]
  )
(* The complete set of graph invariants *)
graphInvariantNames = {"Acyclic", "Algebraic Connectivity", 
   "Average Degree", "Bipartite", "Chromatic Index", 
   "Chromatic Number", "Circumference", "Claw Free", "Clique Number", 
   "Connected", "Density", "Diameter", "Edge Connectivity", 
   "Eulerian", "Genus", "Girth", "Hamiltonian", "Independence Number",
    "Index", "Laplacian Largest Eigenvalue", "Longest Induced Cycle", 
   "Longest Induced Path", "Matching Number", "Maximum Degree", 
   "Minimum Degree", "Minimum Dominating Set", "Number of Components",
    "Number of Edges", "Number of Triangles", "Number of Vertices", 
   "Planar", "Radius", "Regular", "Second Largest Eigenvalue", 
   "Smallest Eigenvalue", "Vertex Connectivity"};

computeGraphInvariants[g_] := (
  il = List[]; (* Create empty graph invariant list *)
  (* Acyclic graph? *)
  AppendTo[il, AcyclicGraphQ[g]];
  (* Algebraic Connectivity *)
  AppendTo[il, algebraicConnectivity[g]];
  (* Compute Average Degree of g *)
  AppendTo[il, Total[VertexDegree[g]]/Length[VertexList[g]]];
  (* Bipartite? *)
  AppendTo[il, BipartiteGraphQ[g]];
  (* Chromatic Index *)
  AppendTo[il, EdgeChromaticNumber[g]]; 
  (* Chromatic Number *)
  AppendTo[il, VertexChromaticNumber[g]];
  (* Find Graph Circumference *)
  cycles = FindCycle[g, Infinity, All];
  AppendTo[il, Max[Table[Length[cycles[[i]]], {i, Length[cycles]}]]];
  (* Is graph claw free *)
  If [Length[FindIsomorphicSubgraph[g, clawGraph]] >= 1,
   AppendTo[il, False],
   AppendTo[il, True];
   ];
  (* Clique number *)
  i = FindClique[g];
  j = Length[i];
  nexMax = 0;
  max = 0;
  For [k = 1, k <= j, k++,
   newMax = Length[i[[k]]];
   If[ newMax > max,
    max = newMax;
    ]
   ];
  AppendTo[il, max];
  (* Connected Graph? *)
  AppendTo[il, ConnectedGraphQ[g]];
  (* Graph Density *)
  AppendTo[il, GraphDensity[g] // N];
  (* Graph Diameter *)
  AppendTo[il, GraphDiameter[g] // N];
  (* Edge Connectivity *)
  AppendTo[il, EdgeConnectivity[g] // N];
  (* Eulerian Graph? *)
  AppendTo[il, EulerianGraphQ[g]];
  (* Need this one *)
  AppendTo[il, "N/A"]; (* Graph Genus *)
  (* Girth *)
  AppendTo[il, IGGirth[g]];
  (* Hamilton Graph? *)
  AppendTo[il, HamiltonianGraphQ[g]];
  (* Using Mathematica built ins to find the largest independent \
vertex set.  This is a brute force algorithm, not very scalable. *)
  iset = FindIndependentVertexSet[g, Infinity, All];
  AppendTo[il, Max[Table[Length[iset[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[iset]}]]];
  (* The index or spectral radius of a graph is the greatest \
eigenvalue of its adjacency matrix. 
  Algorithm finds the maximum eigen value of graph adjancy matrix.*)
  AppendTo[il, Max[Abs[Eigenvalues[AdjacencyMatrix[g]]]]];
  
  (* The Laplacian (AKA Kirchoff) largest eigenvalue of a graph G is \
the largest eigenvalue of its Laplacian matrix L defined by L =D - 
  A where A is the adjacency matrix of G and D is a diagonal matrix \
where Di,i is the degree of vertex i. *)
  AppendTo[il, Max[Abs[Eigenvalues[KirchhoffMatrix[g]]]]];
  (* Longest Induced Cycle *)
  AppendTo[il, "N/A"];
  (* Longest Induced Path *)
  AppendTo[il, "N/A"];
  (* Matching number of g *)
  AppendTo[il, IGMatchingNumber[g]];
  (* Maximum Vertex Degree *)
  AppendTo[il, Max[VertexDegree[g]]];
  (* Minimum Vertex Degree *)
  AppendTo[il, Min[VertexDegree[g]]];
  (* Minimum Dominating Set *)
  AppendTo[il, "N/A"];
  (* Number of connected Components *)
  AppendTo[il, Length[ConnectedComponents[g]]];
  (* Number of edges *)
  AppendTo[il, EdgeCount[g]];
  (* For the triangle count we use the IGraph built-in *)
  AppendTo[il, Length[IGTriangles[g]]];
  (* Number of verteces *)
  AppendTo[il, VertexCount[g]];
  (* Planar graph? *)
  AppendTo[il, PlanarGraphQ[g]];
  (* Graph radius *)
  AppendTo[il, GraphRadius[g]];
  (* Regular graph *)
  AppendTo[il, (Length[Union[VertexDegree[g]]] == 1)];
  (* Second largest eigen value *)
  AppendTo[il, Sort[Abs[Eigenvalues[AdjacencyMatrix[g]]]][[-2]]];
  (* Smallet Eigen Value *)
  AppendTo[il, Min[Abs[Eigenvalues[AdjacencyMatrix[g]]]]];
  (* Vertext Connectivity *)
  AppendTo[il, VertexConnectivity[g]];
  Return[il]
  )

main[] := (
   splash[];
   g = Graph3D[
     RandomGraph[WattsStrogatzGraphDistribution[ 10, 0.05], 
      PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
      PlotLabel -> Framed["Random Watts Strogatz Graph Invariants"]], 
     VertexLabels -> Automatic, EdgeStyle -> White, 
     VertexStyle -> Blue, EdgeLabels -> "Index"];
   (*Print[Framed[g]];*)
   invariants = computeGraphInvariants[g];
   (*data=Dataset[Partition[Riffle[invariantNames,invariahts],2],
   Background\[Rule]{{{Green,White}}},DatasetTheme\[Rule]"Detailed"];
   PrependTo[data,<|"Invariant"->"Value"|>]*)
   
   data = 
    Dataset[MapThread[<|"Invariant" -> #1, "Value" -> #2|> &, {Take[
        graphInvariantNames, Length[invariants]], invariants}], 
     Background -> {{{Green, White}}}, HeaderBackground -> LightGray, 
     HeaderAlignment -> {Automatic, Center}, HeaderStyle -> Bold];
   Print[data];
   );
```

NOTE: I think a brute force method for finding smallest induced sub-graph would be to find the all vertex pair wise shortest path and create the induced subgraph from the vertices in this path.  Likewise, with longest path.  Thoughts?

Comment: Have you looked at the ResourceFunctions, e.g., [`ResourceFunction["FindLongestPath"][g, s, t]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FindLongestPath/)

Comment: What you do is interesting work. Among them, the calculation of Minimum Dominating Set can refer to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65360/computing-domination-numbers-of-graphs

Comment: I do not know whether there is a procedure for the calculation of genus of a graph. I'm actually kind of interested in that. It could even be a separate question.

Comment: Note that exact genus computations are _extremely_ hard. SageMath has a function to do it but it'll break down for as few as 7 vertices. Anything brute-force will be plainly useless. The others are probably solvable for small graphs.

Comment: It seems a brute force approach for minimum dominating set (cardinality of which is the Graph domination Number) can be found via Integer Programming here.  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65360/computing-domination-numbers-of-graphs